# shortcode for recent custom type post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, shortcode, get-posts, recent-posts

I'm not a coder so I may have done some "coding" crimes, apologies. I've bought a theme who has shortcodes for last posts but not for last "custom post type". So I tried to create last "custom post type" function modifying the Last post function provided.
Last post funtion:

```
function get_custom_posts( $params ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'number' => '1',
    'excerpt' => 290,
    'readmore' => 'no',
    'readmoretext' => 'Read more'
), $params ) );

//$latest_posts = get_posts( 'category=0&numberposts=' . $number . '&suppress_filters=false');     OLD
$latest_posts = query_posts( 'cat=0&posts_per_page=' . $number );
wp_reset_query();

$result = '<div class="latest-posts">';
$count = count($latest_posts);
foreach ($latest_posts as $key => $latest_post) {
  $author = get_the_author_meta('nickname', $latest_post->post_author );
  $post_link = get_permalink( $latest_post->ID );
  $date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $latest_post->post_date);
  $category = get_the_category_list( ', ', $parents = '', $latest_post->ID );

  $result .= '<div class="sc-page"><div class="item clearfix">';
  // POST THUMBNAIL
  if (get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_post->ID, 'thumbnail' )) {
      $result .= '<div class="image">';
      $result .= '<a href="' . $post_link . '" class="greyscale">';
      $result .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
      $result .= '</a>';
      $result .= '</div>';
  }

  // POST BODY
  $result .= '<div class="text">';
  $result .= '<div class="title"><h3><a href="' . $post_link. '">' . $latest_post->post_title . '</a></h3></div>';
  if ( $latest_post->post_excerpt ) {
      $result .= '<p>' . $latest_post->post_excerpt . '</p>';
  }
  else {
      $limit = $excerpt;
      $my_text = substr($latest_post->post_content, 0, $limit);
      $pos = strrpos($my_text, " ");
      $my_post_text = substr($my_text, 0, ($pos ? $pos : -1)) . "...";
      $read = "";
  if($readmore == 'yes'){
    $read = '&nbsp;<a href="' . $post_link. '">'.$readmoretext.'</a>';
  }
      $result .= '<p>' . strip_tags($my_post_text) . $read . '</p>';
      //$result .= '<p>' . substr_replace( $latest_post['0']->post_content, '...', 350 ) . '</p>';
  }

  $result .= '</div><!-- /.text -->';

  if ($count - 1 != $key)
  $result .= do_shortcode('[rule]');

  $result .= '</div></div>';
}
$result .= '</div>';

return $result;
}
add_shortcode( "get_posts", "get_custom_posts" );
```

Then I tried to modify it like this, (my custom post type is ait-dir-item):

```
function get_custom_items( $params ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'number' => '1',
    'excerpt' => 290,
    'readmore' => 'no',
    'readmoretext' => 'Read more'
), $params ) );

//$latest_posts = get_posts( 'category=0&numberposts=' . $number . '&suppress_filters=false');     OLD
$latest_items = WP_query( 'post_type' = 'ait-dir-item', 'cat=0&posts_per_page=' . $number );
wp_reset_query();

$result = '<div class="latest-items">';
$count = count($latest_items);
foreach ($latest_items as $key => $latest_item) {
  $author = get_the_author_meta('nickname', $latest_item->post_author );
  $post_link = get_permalink( $latest_item->ID );
  $date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $latest_item->post_date);
  $category = get_the_category_list( ', ', $parents = '', $latest_item->ID );

  $result .= '<div class="sc-page"><div class="item clearfix">';
  // POST THUMBNAIL
  if (get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_item->ID, 'thumbnail' )) {
      $result .= '<div class="image">';
      $result .= '<a href="' . $post_link . '" class="greyscale">';
      $result .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
      $result .= '</a>';
      $result .= '</div>';
  }

  // POST BODY
  $result .= '<div class="text">';
  $result .= '<div class="title"><h3><a href="' . $post_link. '">' . $latest_item->post_title . '</a></h3></div>';
  if ( $latest_item->post_excerpt ) {
      $result .= '<p>' . $latest_item->post_excerpt . '</p>';
  }
  else {
      $limit = $excerpt;
      $my_text = substr($latest_item->post_content, 0, $limit);
      $pos = strrpos($my_text, " ");
      $my_post_text = substr($my_text, 0, ($pos ? $pos : -1)) . "...";
      $read = "";
  if($readmore == 'yes'){
    $read = '&nbsp;<a href="' . $post_link. '">'.$readmoretext.'</a>';
  }
      $result .= '<p>' . strip_tags($my_post_text) . $read . '</p>';
      //$result .= '<p>' . substr_replace( $latest_item['0']->post_content, '...', 350 ) . '</p>';
  }

  $result .= '</div><!-- /.text -->';

  if ($count - 1 != $key)
  $result .= do_shortcode('[rule]');

  $result .= '</div></div>';
}
$result .= '</div>';

return $result;
}
add_shortcode( "get_items", "get_custom_items" );
```

Of course, this function doesn't work... Can someone help me? I want to modify this function instead of installing a plugin because I want to use the same classes so I will have the same design for both shortcodes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not need to create another function. Just add another parameter to the shortcode which could be `$post_type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work with custom post type :

```
function get_custom_posts( $params ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
'number' => '1',
'excerpt' => 290,
'readmore' => 'no',
'cpt' => 'post',
'readmoretext' => 'Read more'
), $params ) );

//$latest_posts = get_posts( 'category=0&numberposts=' . $number .      '&suppress_filters=false');     OLD
$latest_posts = query_posts( 'post_type='.$cpt.'&posts_per_page=' . $number );
wp_reset_query();

$result = '<div class="latest-posts">';
$count = count($latest_posts);
foreach ($latest_posts as $key => $latest_post) {
  $author = get_the_author_meta('nickname', $latest_post->post_author );
  $post_link = get_permalink( $latest_post->ID );
  $date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $latest_post->post_date);
  $category = get_the_category_list( ', ', $parents = '', $latest_post->ID );

  $result .= '<div class="sc-page"><div class="item clearfix">';
 // POST THUMBNAIL
  if (get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_post->ID, 'thumbnail' )) {
      $result .= '<div class="image">';
      $result .= '<a href="' . $post_link . '" class="greyscale">';
      $result .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
      $result .= '</a>';
      $result .= '</div>';
  }

  // POST BODY
  $result .= '<div class="text">';
  $result .= '<div class="title"><h3><a href="' . $post_link. '">' . $latest_post->post_title . '</a></h3></div>';
  if ( $latest_post->post_excerpt ) {
      $result .= '<p>' . $latest_post->post_excerpt . '</p>';
  }
  else {
      $limit = $excerpt;
      $my_text = substr($latest_post->post_content, 0, $limit);
      $pos = strrpos($my_text, " ");
      $my_post_text = substr($my_text, 0, ($pos ? $pos : -1)) . "...";
      $read = "";
  if($readmore == 'yes'){
    $read = '&nbsp;<a href="' . $post_link. '">'.$readmoretext.'</a>';
  }
      $result .= '<p>' . strip_tags($my_post_text) . $read . '</p>';
      //$result .= '<p>' . substr_replace( $latest_post['0']->post_content, '...', 350 ) . '</p>';
  }

  $result .= '</div><!-- /.text -->';

  if ($count - 1 != $key)
  $result .= do_shortcode('[rule]');

  $result .= '</div></div>';
}
$result .= '</div>';

return $result;
}
add_shortcode( "get_posts", "get_custom_posts" );
```

To use it just write `[get_posts cpt="ait-dir-item"]` in your posts

**EDIT: it's bad practise to use query_post() in this context**

Comment: You should not be using `query_posts` for a secondary Loop.

Comment: Thanks @TweetPressFr! It works replacing query_post) and deleting "new". It's just what I needed!

Comment: Sorry @TweetPressFr I meant that It works only with query_post and deleting "new". Why should I use new WP_query instead?

Comment: because it's bad practise to use query_post in this context. I might not work with WP_query because object is not returned.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to me to be this line:

```
$latest_items = WP_query( 'post_type' = 'ait-dir-item', 'cat=0&posts_per_page=' . $number );
```

That is very odd. First, you are missing the `new` keyword. Without it you get an "undefined function" error.

Second, with `WP_Query`, and a number of other functions, you can use a [query-string-like function argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Pass_Tag_Parameters#Tags_with_PHP_function-style_parameters), or an array. You have (broken) elements of both in there, which isn't going to work.

For a query-string-like parameter, you'd need:

```
$latest_items = new WP_query('post_type=ait-dir-item&cat=0&posts_per_page='.$number);
```

See how that is all one string, and yours isn't? You have three distinct strings, an `=` floating loose, and a comma that is going to indicate that you are actually using two parameters and not just one. If you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you'd see errors.

But use an array. Those query-string-like parameters are hard to read, hard to edit, and error prone because of it. At least that is my take.

```
$latest_items = new WP_query( 
  array(
    'post_type' => 'ait-dir-item', 
    'cat' => 0,
    'posts_per_page' => $number,
  )
);
```

Also, the `cat=0` is unnecessary. As near as I can tell, the query is identical with or without it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm review your code throughly but the problem is in the wp_query parameter.so please replace this line to my new one

```
$latest_items = WP_query( 'post_type=ait-dir-item&cat=0&posts_per_page=' . $number )
```

this will help.I'm sure about that.

Comment: no it won't -> `$latest_items = new WP_query( 'post_type=ait-dir-item&cat=0&posts_per_page=' . $number );`

Comment: make sure your custom post type has  posts.
and please use this one after $latest_items
echo "<pre>";print_r($latest_items);echo "</pre>";

Comment: I seriously doubt WP_query will work in this context, it's better using `query_posts()` plus Charlyem is not a coder so why should he print the query?

Comment: It is certainly *not better* to use `query_posts`, @TweetPressFr. You might benefit from reading [this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). And in the direction of Pradipta: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) is a class and as such needs to be instantiated using the [`new`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php) keyword.

Comment: I doubt Charlyem knows queries, he's not a coder. So this answer wasn't good enough to me. But still you're right for query_post(), I should have been more careful.